# Wireguard mesh with star-shaped failover

Tags: routing, networkmanager, iproute, wireguard

I'm currently trying to convert my star-shaped wireguard setup into a mesh-based one with a single server as a fallback node if the direct routes are not reachable. The goal is to reduce latency and make the wireguard layer at home offline-capable without losing the ability to access them via the internet.

My previous wireguard setup relied on a single server 10.0.0.1/24 on the internet. The other peers (laptop, tablet, media server, Android phone) connect to it and can then talk to each other via the server.

In my home network I use static IP addresses to simplify configuration. As a first step towards the hybrid setup described above I've configured all devices as servers and added all other peers on the local network to each peer. This works fine while I'm at home, but breaks once I move a device somewhere else as the static routes added by `wg-quick`'s peer configuration are preferred over the `ip rule` added routing policy modification.

Is there a routing or `ip rule`-based solution to this? I've also been wondering whether `NetworkManager` offers the features I need. `NetworkManager` provides automatic activation of VPN profiles, but these don't seem to work with wireguard profiles.